# AX2012R3 CLR Compile Issues

Tags: c#, clr, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a C# Visual Studio object in my project.

I have numerous forms and classes that use X++ to call CLR methods out of the C# project.  These all worked fine until 2012R3 came out.

A standard compile of anything touching the CLR objects fails, saying the CLR method does not exist.  And if I do a CIL compile to catch the C# objects, it says that failed because the standard methods did not successfully compile--the same ones that couldn't compile due to missing CLR objects.  It appears to be a never-ending circle.

I can take the exact same model file and install in a 2012 R2 system, and everything compiles perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: On one of the non-working classes, I tried setting it at both Client and Server, but neither helped.  I don't think it is a tier issue.

Comment: Have you started looking at more specific differences between the R3 and R2 system besides AX? Are they both using the same version of Visual Studio? Should they be?  Have you seen this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2014/11/24/visual-studio-tools-for-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-r3-cu8-now-requires-microsoft-visual-studio-2013.aspx . Do both systems have the same features of AX12 installed?

Comment: I'll install VS2013 and update the project.  I hadn't seen that article.  Thanks, and I'll let you know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after much research and trial and error, I inadvertently stumbled upon the solution.

As long as the C# project sits down in the isv layer, the R3 server is unable to compile it.  I exported it and then imported the (unchanged) code, which moved it to the usr layer, and now everything works.

Never had this problem on any R2 or older machine, only on AX 2012 R3.

I'm glad we have a workaround.  It isn't ideal, but it does work.

Anyone know why?